# Smaller Space Between Card View in a List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am trying to make the space between card view smaller in a list; currently, the spaces are too large. I've looked everywhere on SO but there doesn't seem to be a good solution so far. I cannot seem to figure out the correct layout to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"


        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sub_txt"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="30dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/img"
                   android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing `cardUseCompatPadding` or set false `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"`

Comment: Thank you-i got rid of the cardUseCompatPadding but then the borders are "fused" together and now there's no space between the cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `cardUseCompatPadding` and add `margin` instead like below:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your card height wrap content

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it seems like "wrap_content makes" the card views very large

Answer (score 0):

CardView by default adds extra padding in platforms pre-Lollipop so as to draw shadows. In Lollipop devices, you will have to set `cardUseCompatPadding=true`, use the line below.

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: I have that added currently and that seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: try these lines as well card_`view:cardElevation="0dp"
 card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"`

Comment: Thank you-I tried that but doesn't seem to make a space between the cards

Comment: @rengineer remove this line `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" ` and remove content padding too along with that you will have to reduce corner padding of card, I tried this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `CardView` height to `wrap_content` and then you can set your `RelativeLayout` height to `match_parent`.

You have given `100dp` to your `CardView` and the `RelativeLayout` height is smaller than that which leads to more space showing between the items.

Comment: Is the CardView height "card_view:layout_constrainedHeight"?